# Delete elements from a list which are less than tolerance value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list `A`. I want to probe each element of `A` such that if any element is less than `tol`, it should be deleted.

But, I am getting an error. I also present the expected output.

```
A= [[9.16435586e-05], [0.000184193464], [9.28353239e-05], [2.22105075e-18]]
tol=1e-12

for i in range(0,len(A)):
    if(A[i]<tol):
        A=A[i]
    else:
        delete(A[i])
```

The error is :

```
in <module>
    if(A[i]<tol):

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'
```

The expected output is :

```
[[9.16435586e-05], [0.000184193464], [9.28353239e-05]]
```

Comment: `A[i] ` will be another list like `[9.16435586e-05]` , so you cannot do `<` directly to it.  Can be something like `A[i][0]`

Comment: `A=A[i]` will get you in trouble too (you are replacing the whole list with one of its elements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this:

```
if A[i][0]<tol :
```

instead of

```
if(A[i]<tol)

A= [[9.16435586e-05], [0.000184193464], [9.28353239e-05], [2.22105075e-18]]
```

your values are nested lists you have to unpack them

There is also some syntax error in your code; there is no `delete` rather `del` is the command. Also it is not advisable to delete items when iterating over them.

Edit:

You can get the desired output by:

```
[[x[0]] for x in A if x[0]>tol]
#[[9.16435586e-05], [0.000184193464], [9.28353239e-05]]
```

Comment: But I don't get the expected output which involves removing the element less than ```tol```.

Comment: The expected output is list of lists: ```[[9.16435586e-05], [0.000184193464], [9.28353239e-05]]```. Not ```[9.16435586e-05, 0.000184193464, 9.28353239e-05]``` as you show.

Comment: please see now.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that you are trying to compare a 'list' with a 'float' as A is a list of list as defined in your code.

So you need to compare the first element of each sublist with the tolerance value.

The following code works.

```
A= [[9.16435586e-05], [0.000184193464], [9.28353239e-05], [2.22105075e-18]]
tol=1e-12

result = []
for i in range(0,len(A)):
    if(A[i][0] >= tol):
        result.append(A[i])

A = result

print(A)
```

Hope this help!